# Transfer a file to remote machine(ubuntu) while running bash remotely

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, rsync, file-transfer

I have written a bash script which I should run on the remote server(ubuntu) with GUI(zenity) interface and I will issue below command on the local machine.

```
sshpass -p $PASS ssh root@$SERVER 'bash' < /tmp/dep.sh | tee >(zenity --progress --title "Tomcat Deployer" --text "Connecting to Tomcat Server..." --width=400 --height=150) >>/tmp/temp.log;
```

I want to transfer a file from my local machine to server and I want to achieve this placing an enter in bash file(`/tmp/dep.sh`) in the above command itself without opening a new session on server.

I prefer below command to transfer the file to server and I should place this in the bash script(/tmp/dep.sh) and it should run on server to copy the file from my local machine. I don't want to specify my local ip as a variable and use as source in the blow command as the script is used on other machines too and thus ip changes. And I should not transfer the file from my local to server writing a separate rsync & ssh creating one more ssh session.

```
rsync --rsh="sshpass -p '$PASS' ssh" '$local:$APPATH/$app.war' /tmp
```

Anybody can do any magic to transfer the file from local to server with the above connected ssh session with the help of above rsync or by other means and without opening new separate connection?

Thank you!

**Edit 1**:

Could this be achieved with single ssh session(single command)?:

```
rsync --rsh="sshpass -p serverpass ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" /home/user1/Desktop/app.war root@192.168.1.5:/tmp;
sshpass -p serverpass ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.1.5 '/etc/init.d/tomcat start'
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use SSH multiplexing. This is done using the `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath` options. Here's [an article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing) on it.

Comment: I never heard this before till you bring it to the view. It seems to b much relevant, trying to understand what I should put in my case....